# Windows Phone 8.1 app not running exactly on Windows 10 Device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Iam running a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal application on Windows 10 Device but it is not navigating to the next pages, but the remaining functionality is completely working fine,

when i run the same application on the Windows Phone 8.1 device it is working fine

when i run the same application on Windows 10 Device and try to navigate to next page, it is saying that Xaml parse Exception was caught, and saying "The Text associated with error could not be found".

Comment: I remember using some sort of "safe navigation" because of this exception, but cannot Google it now... Try search, if no luck I'll look into my old projects once I am on PC.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve similar exceptions while navigating:

```
private async Task SafeNavigation(Type target)
{
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.Navigate(target)); 
}
```

I don't know why this happens though..